# Defining component on data or computed section vue

Tags: vue.js

I am new to vue and wanted to know if it is possible to define my component in my data or computed section ?

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <NavBar :items="['Home', 'Database', 'About']" />
    <ActiveComponent />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from './components/NavBar.vue'
import routes from './routes/index.js';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    NavBar,
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      activeLocation: window.location.pathname,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ActiveComponent() {
      return routes[this.activeLocation] || routes.notFound
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

You see what I am trying to do. I want to use `<ActiveComponent />` but I am defining it in computed section based on the route selected.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Are you looking at something like Dynamic Components? 

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: @FedericoQuagliotto I just found a way to do what I was looking for! should I answer my own question here ? what is the flow ?

Comment: have you seen https://router.vuejs.org/ vue-router? i think that swap the component on the fly on this way is a bit dangerous.. have a look to the lifecycle of a vue component (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram)

Comment: @FedericoQuagliotto I looked into the router but I am not able to get my base component (template) to exist everywhere with it! I want NavBar to be present on every page. But with router, I would have to define that NavBar component on every page I am making!

Comment: well… you can also declare your main template and put in there the `<router-view>` tag.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/ have a look to the example html parts

Comment: @FedericoQuagliotto wow! that will work totally! Thank you a loads. I am trying to work it out on my own, but if you can make a working code and post it as an answer! I would mark it selected

Answer (score 1):

I thought so hard about it that I realized that I can not use `this` inside my components key , but I can use globals like so

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    NavBar,
    ActiveComponent: routes[window.location.pathname.toLowerCase()] || routes.notFound
  }
}
```